# How do i make my expo app render a mobile view on an android tablet just like bolt or uber renders on a tablet?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, mobile-development

I'm building an app using expo and i would like it to have a mobile view on android tablets but i don't know how this can be done. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @ThilinaChamathHewagama i've tried using <supports-screens>attribute in AndroidManifest.xml but nothing is happening. I just moved my project from Expo Managed to Bare Workflow.